# does placing of script tag in html file alter the output?

Tags: javascript, html, func

I tried placing a javascript code  in the head tag but the browser didn't give any output but when I placed the script tag under the div I targeted in the function it works perfectly. Why does that happen?

below is the code i tried:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>    
    function myValues(){         
        var i, max = 0;       
            for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
                if(arguments[i] > max){
                        max = arguments[i];
                        }                                   
        }
        return max;         
    }
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myValues(1, 5, 0, 55, 78, 8989, 3166);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It wont work in the `head` tag because the DOM has not loaded yet. It wont know where the demo element is yet.

If you put it on an `onload` function it would execute after the page has loaded. If you moved it down the page below the main DOM it would work too as its loaded the element before the script is run.

Answer (score 0):

Because the script is run immediately, and the page has not yet created the `#demo` element.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your script tag somewhere after your `div#demo`. because you need it in your script. best place is to put it before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `<script>` tag above the `<div>`, the element won't exist when the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will the script when it appears in the code, so placing it before the HTML you want to change will do nothing as the demo element doesn't exist yet. You should place the script after the html for the demo element